# Hide/Show column in ColumnTree ExtJS using Manual Approach Not Working

Tags: extjs

I have a `ColumTree` `Ext.us.Tree.ColumnTree`, I want to hide/show a column conditionally, I used config like `hidden` and `setVisible`, but it will not work,

```
var tree = new Ext.ux.tree.ColumnTree({
        width: 990,
        height: 300,
        rootVisible: false,
        autoScroll: true,
        title: '<s:property value="lblStockTotal"/>',
        renderTo: 'tree-div',

        columns: [
            {
                id: 'lblProduct',
                header: '<s:property value="lblProduct"/>'+' -> '+'<s:property value="lblProgram"/>'+' -> ' +'<s:property value="lblCountry"/>',
                dataIndex: 'Product',
                width: 230

            },
            {
                header: '<s:property value="lblTotalVolume"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'TotalVolume'

            },
            {
                header: '<s:property value="lblTradingStock"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'TradingStock'

            },
            {
                header: '<s:property value="lblMarketplace"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'Marketplace',
                hidden:true

            },
            {
                header: '<s:property value="lblAuction"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'Auction',
                hidden:true

            },
            {
                header: '<s:property value="lblWarehouse"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'Warehouse',
                hidden:true // NOT Working

            }

        ],

        loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
            dataUrl: 'stocktotaldata.action',
            uiProviders: {
                'col': Ext.ux.tree.ColumnNodeUI
            }
        }),

        root: new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
            text: 'Tasks'
        })
    });
```

**MANUAL APPROACH**

What I have Done, I split up each column into variable like col1,col2 etc and now I want to render those column using if condition , which is even not work, when I add up all those column like col1+col2+col3, that will encountered an error

```
masterColumn=column1+column2+column3+column4+column5+column6+colEnd;

var column1=[
            {
                id: 'lblProduct',
                header: '<s:property value="lblProduct"/>'+' -> '+'<s:property value="lblProgram"/>'+' -> ' +'<s:property value="lblCountry"/>',
                dataIndex: 'Product',
                width: 230

            },;
            var column2=
            {
                header: '<s:property value="lblTotalVolume"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'TotalVolume'

            },;
            var column3=
            {
                header: '<s:property value="lblTradingStock"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'TradingStock'

            };
            var column4=
            ,{
                header: '<s:property value="lblMarketplace"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'Marketplace',
                hidden:true

            };

            var column5=
            ,{
                header: '<s:property value="lblAuction"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'Auction',
                align:'right',
                hidden:true,

            };
            var column6=
            ,{
                header: '<s:property value="lblWarehouse"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'Warehouse',
                hidden:true

            };
            var colEnd=];




var tree = new Ext.ux.tree.ColumnTree({
        width: 990,
        height: 300,
        rootVisible: false,
        autoScroll: true,
        title: '<s:property value="lblStockTotal"/>',
        renderTo: 'tree-div',

        columns: masterColumn,

        loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
            dataUrl: 'stocktotaldata.action',
            uiProviders: {
                'col': Ext.ux.tree.ColumnNodeUI
            }
        }),

        root: new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
            text: 'Tasks'
        })
    });
```

Comment: you can find properties and methods applicable to `Ext.ux.tree.ColumnTree` here : 
 https://community.zarafa.com/webapp/#!/api/Ext.ux.tree.ColumnTree

Comment: `hidden:true` not working

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tree = new Ext.ux.tree.ColumnTree({
        width: 990,
        height: 300,
        rootVisible: false,
        autoScroll: true,
        title: '<s:property value="lblStockTotal"/>',
        renderTo: 'tree-div',

        columns: [
            this.column1 = {
                id: 'lblProduct',
                header: '<s:property value="lblProduct"/>'+' -> '+'<s:property value="lblProgram"/>'+' -> ' +'<s:property value="lblCountry"/>',
                dataIndex: 'Product',
                width: 230

            },
            this.column2 = {
                header: '<s:property value="lblTotalVolume"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'TotalVolume'

            },
            this.column3 = {
                header: '<s:property value="lblTradingStock"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'TradingStock'

            },
            this.column4 = {
                header: '<s:property value="lblMarketplace"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'Marketplace',
                hidden:true

            },
            this.column5 = {
                header: '<s:property value="lblAuction"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'Auction',
                hidden:true

            },
            this.column6 = {
                header: '<s:property value="lblWarehouse"/>',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'Warehouse',
                hidden:true // NOT Working

            }

        ],

        loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
            dataUrl: 'stocktotaldata.action',
            uiProviders: {
                'col': Ext.ux.tree.ColumnNodeUI
            }
        }),

        root: new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
            text: 'Tasks'
        })
    });
```

we can use the reference using this, and later use this reference in the instance you have created and then can use hide and show method to hide or show.

Comment: Hii can you implement the same, i am not able to get you

Comment: shall we need to add listeners to do the same

Comment: then how we can hide the column, can you post some sample snippet for the same, because I need to show/hide on the basis of conditions

Comment: Hey Ganesh you there ?

Comment: Ganesh you there?